# Remove multiple patterns of a file

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I've got the following file, lets call it **user.txt**:

```
2020/06/30 22:02:58 > [+] VALID USERNAME:   admin@spookysec.local
2020/06/30 22:03:58 > [+] VALID USERNAME:   admin-svc@spookysec.local
2020/06/30 22:04:58 > [+] VALID USERNAME:   backup@spookysec.local
2020/06/30 22:05:58 > [+] VALID USERNAME:   harry@spookysec.local
2020/06/30 22:06:58 > [+] VALID USERNAME:   wrgwrsd@spookysec.local
2020/06/30 22:07:58 > [+] VALID USERNAME:   brssdb@spookysec.local
2020/06/30 22:09:58 > [+] VALID USERNAME:   a@spookysec.local
2020/06/30 22:10:58 > [+] VALID USERNAME:   adm@spookysec.local
2020/06/30 22:11:58 > [+] VALID USERNAME:   admifdfdsn@spookysec.local
```

I want to remove multiple patterns of every line to just get the usernames (e.g. admin, admin-sv) with one username per line.
I tried two seperate sed's what worked fine,

```
sed -r 's/.{16}$//' user.txt > user2.txt
```

and after that

```
sed -r 's/.{42}//' user2.txt > user3.txt
```

but I think there is a faster and sexier way to do that.

Especially this command

```
sed -r 's/(@\D+)$//' user.txt > user2.txt
```

doesn't work. I wanted to delete the @ and every character hereafter...

Does anyone have a clue what I did wrong and possibly a solution? It would be best if I can reach my goal with sed or grep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this `sed`:

```sh
sed -E 's/.*[[:blank:]]|@.*//g' file

admin
admin-svc
backup
harry
wrgwrsd
brssdb
a
adm
admifdfdsn
```

**Explanation:**

- `.*[[:blank:]]`: Match any string of 0 or more characters followed by a whitespace
- `|`: OR
- `@.*`: Match `@` and everything after that

Comment: This is a good answer. It works on both Microsoft and Unix text files (CRLF vs LF line ends), because `[[:blank:]` doesn't match carriage return (CR), compared to `[[:space:]]`, which does.

Comment: Yeah thanks much for your answer and especially for your description of the components of the command

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following codes.

***1st solution:*** With `awk`, this could be done in more simpler way, try following once.

```
awk -F'VALID USERNAME:[[:space:]]+|@' '{print $2}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using `awk` programing here. Making `VALID USERNAME:[[:space:]]+|@` as field separator for whole Input_file and printing 2nd field of each line as per requirement.

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using GNU `grep` please try following.

```
grep -oP 'VALID USERNAME:[[:space:]]+\K[^@]*' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** using GNU `grep`'s `-oP` option where -o to print only matched value and `-P` to enable PCRE regex. In main program of `grep` matching `VALID USERNAME:[[:space:]]+` regex followed by a `\K`(which will forget previously matched values in order to not to print them), then matching everything just before @ to get actual user names as per OP's shown samples.

Answer (score 2):

Another variant using sed with a capture group, using group 1 `\1` in the replacement:

```
sed -E 's/.*[[:blank:]]([^@[:blank:]]+)@.*/\1/' file
```

- `.*[[:blank:]]` Match until the last space
- `([^@[:blank:]]+)` Capture in group 1 matching  1+ chars other than `@` or spaces
- `@.*` Match `@` and the rest of the line

Output

```
admin
admin-svc
backup
harry
wrgwrsd
brssdb
a
adm
admifdfdsn
```

---

Another option using awk, you could split the last column on `@`

If the split has returned 2 parts, you can print the first part:

```
awk '{
    nr=split($(NF), a, "@")
    if (nr==2) print a[1]
}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
sed 's/.*[[:space:]]\([^[:space:]]\)/\1/; s/@.*//'
```

The slight difference between this and anubhava's (good) answer, is just that it still works if there is stray white space at the end of a line.

Possibly unnecessary/paranoid, but depending on the situation, I like to allow for stuff like that.

If the columns vary, you could use:

```
sed -E 's/(.*VALID[[:space:]]+USERNAME:[[:space:]]+)([^@[:space:]]+)(.*)/\2/'
```

This matches `VALID USERNAME:` anywhere in the line, and prints the next field, up to but not including the first `@` or whitespace character. You could also change the pattern to just `USERNAME:` or similar, depending on your data.

Finally, these variations skip a line if `@` is not found (ie. the email field is empty or invalid):

```
sed -n 's/.*[[:blank:]]\([^[:space:]]\)/\1/; s/@.*//p'
sed -En 's/(.*VALID[[:space:]]+USERNAME:[[:space:]]+)([^@]+)(@.*)/\2/p'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE 's/.*\<([^@]*)@.*/\1/p' file
```

Capture and print the word before the last `@` character.